# Editing your previous questions to improve formatting and clarity really works?

Tags: discussion, support, questions, edits

These days my past questions have not been well-received, and I can get blocked from being asking any question. After that I took that into consideration and edited my question in hope that my question will get more impressive. But my question is that does it really helps me to prevent from getting blocked from being asking any question ?

[image]

Comment: If you improve the quality of your past questions, then they are less likely to receive (more) downvotes, and may even garner upvotes, *over time*. Since the quality of your past contributions is, in part, measured by the score on your existing questions, it *does* help, yes.

Comment: But it may be that the "past questions" it's talking about are ones that have been deleted. Do you have any of those?

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, future improvement on the question will rarely get you out of the negative votes. This is because voters vote on the question in front of them and do not get notified if the question is change or reworded, leaving the OP (original poster) frustrated in trying to get votes back. Stack-overflows question asking process can be more about the voter misunderstanding the question at first and then moving on never knowing the changes to the question.

**Way to Prevent this**:

*Use stack-overflow as a last resource*: stack-overflow wants the best questions and the best answers it has little to no sympathy for those who don’t word things perfectly the first time.

*Use google*: research as much as you can about the topic before asking to ensure that people don’t get confused.

*Ask specific questions*: users won’t take the time to decipher what is being asked.

*Provide the code*: programmers want to see all the code that is being worked with, they can’t give you an outcome if you don’t give them the input.

**Ways to climb out of the hole**:

*Ask a friend to help*: friends are great and often don’t see it as a big deal (we’ve all been there)

*Change the question* to the most specific question you can(although I said this rarely helps it will help for the tip below this)

*Go to the chat room*: chat rooms are great with helping with this type of thing (but don’t be that guy, you know the guy that goes into every chat room asking for up- votes) if the chat room’s rules allow it just ask them if they can review the question and if they could give you any tips (they’ll probably up-vote and give you great tips)

Comment: "it has little to no sympathy for those who don’t word things perfectly the first time" Very true. It's just the way it is, with so many new questions coming in all the time. Closed questions get a second chance in the Reopen review queue, but I'm not sure how many actually succeed there. Questions that don't get closed... don't get much of a second chance at all.

Comment: I've actually worked in the chat room with the bot recognizing those reopens and it's very few. Most of them are listed as Unclear and closed.